# Karaf - TransactionRequiredException

Tags: java, jta, apache-karaf, karaf

I am running Karaf, I have a DataSource in persistence.xml (pointing to a SQL Server DB), and I am trying to execute an insert query.

But I am getting this exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query at
  org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:71)
```

My transaction-type is set to JTA.
I think I need to configure some transactions but I am not very familiar with this. I think it's something simple but I don't find many ideas when googling.

What do I need to change in my XML descriptors (persistence.xml or blueprints.xml)?

Please provide some sample XML snippet. Many thanks in advance.

```
     71 | Active |  80 | 2.3.0               | Apache Aries JPA Container API
     73 | Active |  80 | 2.3.0               | Apache Aries JPA container
     74 | Active |  80 | 2.3.0               | Apache Aries JPA support
     76 | Active |  80 | 1.1.1               | Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint
     77 | Active |  80 | 2.1.0               | Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint
     78 | Active |  80 | 1.3.0               | Apache Aries Transaction Manager
```

Comment: Are you using Aries JPA and if yes what version of it?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider I added this to the question. Also, Karaf version is: 4.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [aries jpa examples](https://github.com/apache/aries/tree/trunk/jpa/examples). There are examples for blueprint and declarative services. For blueprint there is support for standard annotations like @PersistenceContext and @Transactional.

For DS you can use the JPATemplate to run code in a transaction and with an EntityManager.